# EF Core join table with multiple condition with nullable property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have the following table structures:

```
public class Delegate {
    public int DelegateId {get;set;}
    public int? NotificationTypeId { get; set; }
    public NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }
}

    public class TrainingNotification {
        public int TrainingNotificationId {get;set;}
public int NotificationTypeId {get;set;}
        public int DelegateId {get;set;}
        public virtual Delegate Delegate {get;set;}
    }
```

One to Many between Delegate and TrainingNotification

```
public class NotificationType {
    public int NotificationTypeId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Delegate> Delegates {get;set;}
}
```

Want to retrieve the TrainingNotification for the NotificationTypeId in Delegate.

```
    var delegates21 = await from tn in _context.TrainingNotification
                            join cd in _context.Delegate on
                            new { tn.DelegateId, tn.NotificationTypeId } equals
                            new { cd.DelegateId, cd.NotificationTypeId }
```

but getting error
type of one of the expression in the join clause in incorrect

Can anyone help how to fix this?

Here is the test data and expected result:

```
Delegate:
DelegateId  NotificationTypeId
100             1
8201            2
101             null


TrainginNotification:
TrainignNotificationId  DelegateId  NotificationTypeId
1                           8201        1
2                           8201        2
3                           100         1


NotificationType:
NotificationTypeId      Name
1                       InviteEmail
2                       ReminderEmail

Retrieve users who hasnt got reminder emails:

Result:

DelegateId      
100
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you haven't identified the parts of your anonymous type explicitly.  Try:

```
 var delegates21 = await from tn in _context.TrainingNotification
                        join cd in _context.Delegate on
                        new { did = tn.DelegateId, nid = tn.NotificationTypeId } equals
                        new { did = cd.DelegateId, nid = cd.NotificationTypeId }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't join on DelegateId and NotificationTypeId. Both of these columns are different

Comment: I don't see `NotificationTypeId` defined on `TrainingNotification`. Is it supposed to be there?

Comment: i have updated the table. Sorry missed to add NotificationTypeId in TrainingNotification.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi are you trying to join on 2 separate Ids (delegateId and NotificationTypeId)?

Comment: yes. i have updated my query and also updated with sample data and expected result.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi I think you were just missing naming the anonymous types - updated

Comment: Yes it worked. Can i use something like  var delegates21 = await( from tn in _context.TrainingNotification
                        join cd in _context.Delegate on
                        new { did = tn.DelegateId, nid = tn.NotificationTypeId } equals
                        new { did = cd.DelegateId, nid = cd.NotificationTypeId } select cd).ToListAsync()

Comment: Yes - you can add a select to the end of it, if that's you're question

Answer (score 0):

Since `NotificationTypeId` is nullable on the `Delegate` type but not on the `TrainingNotifcation` type, you can cast the `TrainingNotification.NotificationTypeId` as `int?`:

```c#
var delegates21 = await from tn in _context.TrainingNotification
                            join cd in _context.Delegate on
                            new { tn.DelegateId, (int?)tn.NotificationTypeId } equals
                            new { cd.DelegateId, cd.NotificationTypeId }
```

That should work just fine.